# Determining date and time to schedule alarm

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app to remind user about upcoming appointments. Let just say
User appointment will be on 21: 9: 2016 . So alarm will start notifying him before two days from appoinment
Currently I know how to set alarm at specific time   but don’t know how to set alarm from 1 date to another date .
Here is my code for setting alarm for specific date .

```
  public static void setUpAlarm(Context context, String time, String appointment_id) {

    int month = Integer.valueOf(DataBaseManager.getInstance(context).getMonthFromDateTime(time));
    int year = Integer.valueOf(DataBaseManager.getInstance(context).getYearFromDateTime(time));
    int day = Integer.valueOf(DataBaseManager.getInstance(context).getDayofTheMonth(time));
    int hour = Integer.valueOf(DataBaseManager.getInstance(context).getHourFromDateTime(time));
    int min = Integer.valueOf(DataBaseManager.getInstance(context).getMinuteFromDateTime(time));
        int sec =0;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(year, --month, day, hour, min, 0);
        long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();



        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciver.class);
        intent.putExtra("service_id", appointment_id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.valueOf(alarmCode), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

// db functions for getting day , hour , month , year from datetime

```
    public String getDayofTheMonth(String datetime) {
    db = this.DataBase.getReadableDatabase();


    String selectQuery = "select strftime('%d','" + datetime + "') as result";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));
    }
    return "";
}


public String getSecondFromDateTime(String datetime) {
    db = this.DataBase.getReadableDatabase();


    String selectQuery = "select strftime('%S','" + datetime + "') as result";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));
    }
    return "";
}

public String getMinuteFromDateTime(String datetime) {
    db = this.DataBase.getReadableDatabase();


    String selectQuery = "select strftime('%M','" + datetime + "') as result";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));
    }
    return "";
}
```

function for geting past dates from future date

```
public List<String> getPastDatesFromSpecificDate(String noOfDays, String datetime) {
    db = this.Database.getReadableDatabase();
    List<String> dateslist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = -1; i < Integer.valueOf(datetime); i++) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT date('" + datetime + "','-" + i + " day') as datetime; ";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("past_dates",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("datetime")));
            dateslist.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("datetime")));
        }
    }

    return dateslist;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get previous date like this.

```
private String getYesterdayDateString() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: can you show me how to above specific task using alarm manager?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Sounds like you want to set a recurring alarm every day at the same time-of-day. To set the alarm you apparently need a count of milliseconds since the epoch of start of 1970 in UTC.

If your Question is not this, you should edit the Question for further info as it is not written clearly.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes that are now outmoded by the java.time classes. Much of that java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in The [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Use the `LocalTime` class to represent the alarm time for each day.

```
LocalTime alarmTime = LocalTime.of( 6 , 0 , 0 );
```

Get current date. Time zone required as the date is not the same simultaneously around the globe.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Set the alarm for tomorrow.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
```

Combine the three parts together to create a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object to represent a specific moment on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = 
    ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , alarmTime , z );
```

Extract a count of milliseconds since epoch. We can get that from an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 
    zdt.toInstant()
       .toEpochMilli() ;
```